# PostgreSQL error 'Could not connect to server: No such file or directory'

Tags: postgresql, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

Like some others I am getting this error when I run rake db:migrate in my project or even try most database tasks for my [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) 3.2 applications.

> PGError (could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the
>   server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I installed [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) with [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) a long time ago and following an attempted installation of [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) recently my PostgreSQL install has never been the same. I'm running OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard.

What's wrong and how do I better understand how PostgreSQL is and should be setup on my Mac?

So far (I think) this tells me that PostgreSQL is not running(?).

```
ps -aef|grep postgres                                                                                                   (ruby-1.9.2-p320@jct-ana) (develop) ✗
  501 17604 11329   0   0:00.00 ttys001    0:00.00 grep postgres
```

But does this tell me that PostgreSQL is running?

```
✪ launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.4/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist                                                        (ruby-1.9.2-p136) 
homebrew.mxcl.postgresql: Already loaded
```

How do I fix this? what am I not seeing?

PS: `~/Library/LaunchAgents` includes two PostgreSQL .plist files. I am not sure if that's relevant.

```
org.postgresql.postgres.plist
homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

I tried the following and got a result as below.

**$ psql -p 5432 -h localhost**

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've read since that this is occuring because OS X installs its own version of PostgreSQL and Homebrew installs a different version in a different place and the PostgreSQL commands are looking in the /tmp/ directory. You'll need to search more on Stack Overflow, but basically you symlink PostgreSQL so that anything looking in that tmp path actually finds the real path, if that makes sense.

This is the link where I found a few more things to try, specifically doing the symlink as per above, *[Mac OSX Lion Postgres does not accept connections on /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240516)*. I still wish someone would put together a decent explanation of the concepts behind installing PostgreSQL on OS X and why it's all so difficult.

Latest insights to help with troubleshooting:

```
$ which psql // This tells you which PostgreSQL you are using when you run $ psql.
```

Then run:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

The key thing to take into account is this:

**Ensure that the path entry for the copy of PostgreSQL you want to run COMES BEFORE the path to the OS X system's PostgreSQL.**

This is a core requirement which decides which PostgreSQL gets run and is what I'm told leads to most of these issues.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I see you haven't marked one. None of these help me either.

Comment: It's still mostly vodoo and strange incarnations to get it working. I just added [Edit 2] above with a link with some more suggestions and how to do the symlink as per my edit comments. The Symlink worked for me in the end but I think I also uninstalled and reinstalled postgres and homebrew in there along the way, so hard to know exactly what made the difference. Good luck. Report back if you discover anything new, with 15,000 views on this question it's something giving lots of people pain!

Comment: @AndrasGyomrey I've just come back from RailsCamp15 in Australia and people said a key was to get your path file right, I've editing in Edit 3 above to explain this.

Comment: Keep in mind that launchctl reporting something as loaded does NOT necessarily mean it's up and running. You should take a look at https://bigsql.com/ as an alternative; works on Mac and has a good management UI.

Answer (score 114):

Check there is no postmaster.pid in your postgres directory, probably `/usr/local/var/postgres/`

remove this and start server.

Check - https://github.com/mperham/lunchy is a great wrapper for launchctl.

Comment: This worked for me.  I just fresh installed yosemite, and loaded postgres from homebrew.  Worked fine the first time I used it, but had this issue after a restart.  So, can you explain why this worked?

Comment: worked for me, but for newbs, can someone explain why and how safe this is

Comment: @AlexanderMills *if* you delete `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` *while* a postgres instance is running, you will have to instances which is bad. Bad, as in non-deterministic database behavior, race conditions etc. But if you are sure no postgres is running, it is safe to delete

Answer (score 64):

For me, this works

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

You may need to also restart Postgres after removing this file with either of the following:

```
brew services restart postgresql
# or 
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Comment: In my case, after deleting the pid,  I needed to restart postgresql with ```pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start```

Comment: I also had to restart postgres, when installed by homebrew, you can do it like this: `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: I am in docker env `No such file or directory` in my case

Comment: rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory

Answer (score 58):

"[Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/)" is a better fix if you are on OS X

---

Here is the fix:

1. Stop the database
2. `cd /var`
3. `sudo rm -r pgsql_socket`
4. `sudo ln -s /tmp pgsql_socket`
5. `chown _postgres:_postgres pgsql_socket`
6. Restart PostgreSQL (not your computer)

More information is available at "[postgresql 9.0.3. on Lion Dev Preview 1](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/5004)".

Comment: Errors back for me and this fix didn't help. I feel like Im bumping around in a dark room in working to understand what is actually going on and a process to apply a fix myself. Would it be possible for you to explain how I could diagnose and fix this issue?

Comment: Works for me. Feels a bit weird to chown `/tmp` to _postgres, but hey :)

Comment: postgresapp works, but why i cant start my server in terminal? After i quit this app, problem come back as expected.

Comment: This worked for me, but note that you must be root or use sudo to execute #2 - 4. Also, please clarify step #5 - you only need to restart postgres, not the computer.

Comment: This worked for me. (The old answer, not postgresapp)

Comment: Capital letters don't make a better answer. It is still perfectly fine to install and run Postgres through Homebrew (services.)

Comment: The old answer helped with a build from source I'd done on OS X 10.11. But it seems like it might be better to try setting unix_socket_directories = '/tmp' in postgresql.conf... then again, I tried that, and it didn't seem to make a bit of difference. Anyone have a guess about what might be going on?

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me for the error you mentioned. Do *one* of these:

1. Possibly change your default port specified in the `postgres.conf` file,
   if you have used something other than the default port  `5432` while installing.
2. Change the port number in `postgresql.conf` and restart the DB server.
3. Instead of `psql` type the full command:

   ```
   psql -p 5432 -h localhost
   ```

   - server name and the port no

Comment: 1. I think my install would have been as per the defaults.

Comment: 2. I could change this, any implications of changing the port?

Comment: 3. Added my output from 3 above.

Comment: Option 3 worked with custom port. Because I have multiple pg servers installed (PostgreSQL 9.1, 9.2 and 9.3), I had also to point to the right psql.

Answer (score 13):

**If you are running Homebrew, uninstall Postgresql end pg gems:***

```
$ gem uninstall pg
$ brew uninstall postgresql
```

**Download and run the following script to fix permission on /usr/local:***
https://gist.github.com/rpavlik/768518

```
$ ruby fix_homebrew.rb
```

**Then install Postgres again and pg gem:***

```
$ brew install postgresql  
$ initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

**To have launchd start postgresql at login run:**

```
$ ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

**Or start manually.**

**Install pg gem**

```
$ gem install pg
```

I hope have helped

Comment: From `brew info postgres`: `ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg`

Comment: wouldn't this delete the records in the db?

Comment: `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8` works. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this by upgrading postgres.

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Then I had to also upgrade the databases to be compatible with the new major version, because I upgraded from 10 to 11.

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

(source https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18760#issuecomment-410533581)

Comment: I got this error Error: No postgresql 9.3.* version installed!

Answer (score 8):

I had that problem when I upgraded Postgres to 9.3.x. The quick fix for me was to downgrade to whichever 9.2.x version I had before (no need to install a new one).

```
$ ls /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/
9.2.4
9.3.2
$ brew switch postgresql 9.2.4
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
<open a new Terminal tab or window to reload>
$ psql
```

"[Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula/4158763#4158763)" offers a much more comprehensive explanation along with alternative ways to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and clear instructions to repeat your fix. That link you included sure is comprehensive, Im not currently having issues with postgres so am not sure how much this is useful to others as yet, but to anyone else if you find this useful, please comment here.

Comment: I find it useful and relevant, although maybe not directly. He solved the problem by just switching versions, using brew, which is a fairly common tool, and just repeated the steps, so far, great, the link gets into more issues specific to brew, however, so I can see your questioning it's value in the context of the OP's question.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this error when running on Mac 10.15.5 using homebrew and seems to be a more updated solution that works where the ones above did not.

There is a file called postmaster.pid which should is automatically deleted when postresql exits.

If it doesn't do the following

- brew services stop postgresql <--- Failing to exit before rm could corrupt db
- sudo rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid

Answer (score 5):

So for a lot of the issues here, it seems that people were already running psql and had to remove `postmaster.pid`. However, I did not have that issue as I never even had postgres installed in my system properly.

Here's a solution that worked for me in MAC OSX Yosemite

1. I went to http://postgresapp.com/ and downloaded the app.
2. I moved the app to Application/ directory
3. I added it to $PATH by adding this to .bashrc or .bash_profile or .zshrc : `export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin`
4. I ran the postgres from the Applications directory and ran the command again and it worked.

Hope this helps! Toodles!

Also, this answer helped me the most: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21503349/3173748

Comment: Doesn't this point to the Postgres app rather than the brew installation? That can cut you off from some helpful packages (pgrouting for example, which you can't install for the Postgres app which has caused me endless grief and here I am now)

Answer (score 4):

When you run:
psql -p 5432 -h localhost
it does not use the loopback driver but uses a real socket and hence you need to configure postgres to accept socket connections. Hence even though pgadmin and other clients may work, psql will not.

You need to change both the postgresql.conf file and the pg_hba.conf files so allow connection over a real socket. This will also allow connection from a remote ip which is why it is disabled by default.

These files are in the data directory but the actual location can be different depending on how postgres was installed. With postgres running, run the command:

```
ps -ef | grep postmaster
```

These two files are the -D directory (maybe /usr/local/pgsql/data).

For the postgresql.conf file, uncomment the listen_address and change it to be:

```
listen_address = '*'
```

For the pg_hba.conf add the line:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know Mac or Homebrew, but I know PostgreSQL very well.

You want to figure out where the logs are from PostgreSQL trying to start and what the socket directory is for PostgreSQL.  By default when you build PG, the socket directory is /tmp/.  If you didn't change that when you built PG and then you started PG, you should be able to see a socket file in /tmp if you do: ls -al /tmp

The socket file starts with a ".", so you won't see it with the '-a' to ls.

If you don't see a socket there, and you don't see anything from ps awux | grep postgres, then PG is probably not running, or maybe it is and it's the OSX-installed one.  What might be happening is that you might be getting a conflict on listening on port 5432 on localhost- use netstat -anp to see what, if anything, is listening on 5432.  If a Mac OSX PG is already listening on that port then that might be the problem.

Hope that helps.  I have heard that homebrew can make things a bit ugly and a lot of people I've talked to encourage using a VM instead.

Comment: Thanks for contributing on this. If it helps give you a bit more background, homebrew simply runs this script when installing postgres. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/postgresql.rb I'm hoping you might give it a look over and possibly share any further insights from what you find. What I think people are needing is an easier way to debug why they are getting this error so they know what action to take.

Comment: Based on what I can understand of that script, there is a "postgres.log" in a "var" directory, possibly under HOMEBREW_PREFIX.  That log file will contain information about PG trying to start up (including if it failed to start for some reason).  Here is an example message showing PG failing to start due to another process listening on port 5432:

Comment: 2016-12-19 09:11:59.582 EST [20669] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
2016-12-19 09:11:59.582 EST [20669] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2016-12-19 09:11:59.582 EST [20669] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2016-12-19 09:11:59.582 EST [20669] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2016-12-19 09:11:59.582 EST [20669] LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: Further, it looks like that script does not change the default socket directory, so that should be /tmp/.  You could look in the PG data directory (which appears to be {HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/var/postgres) for the postgresql.conf file and look for "unix_socket_directories".  It is commented out by default but has the default set, eg:

Comment: #unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'       # comma-separated list of directories

Comment: If PostgreSQL has started, you should be able to see a socket file in /tmp by doing: ls -l /tmp/.s.PGSQL*  If you do not see any files returned by that command then chances are your homebrew PG install is not running and you need to review the log file to see why.

Answer (score 2):

for me command `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` didn't work cause I installed a specific version of postgresql with homebrew.

the right command is `rm /usr/local/var/postgres@10/postmaster.pid`.

then `brew services restart postgresql@10`.

Answer (score 1):

**The Cause**

Lion comes with a version of postgres already installed and uses those binaries by default. In general you can get around this by using the full path to the homebrew postgres binaries but there may be still issues with other programs.

**The Solution**

> curl http://nextmarvel.net/blog/downloads/fixBrewLionPostgres.sh | sh

Via

http://nextmarvel.net/blog/2011/09/brew-install-postgresql-on-os-x-lion/

Answer (score 1):

One reason you get this error is that your local postgres database shuts down when you restart your computer.  In a new terminal window, simply type:

```
$psql -h localhost
```

to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Hello world :)
**The best but strange way for me was to do next things.**
**1)** Download [postgres93.app](http://postgresapp.com/) or other version. Add this app into /Applications/ folder.

**2)** Add a row (command) into the file `.bash_profile` (which is in my home directory):

```
export PATH=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/:$PATH
```

It's a PATH to `psql` from `Postgres93.app`. The row (command) runs every time console is started.

**3)** Launch `Postgres93.app` from `/Applications/` folder. It starts a local server (port is "5432" and host is "localhost").

**4)** After all of this manipulations I was glad to run `$ createuser -SRDP user_name` and other commands and to see that it worked! `Postgres93.app` can be made to run every time your system starts.

**5)** Also if you wanna see your databases graphically you should install `PG Commander.app`. It's good way to see your postgres DB as pretty data-tables

Of, course, it's helpful only for local server. I will be glad if this instructions help others who has faced with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had PostgreSQL 9.3 and got the same error,

> Could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running
>   on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting     TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432?

I fixed this using:

```
chmod 777  /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/pg_hba.conf 
service postgresql-9.3 restart
```

It works for me.

Comment: This file doesn't exist for me

Answer (score 1):

for what it's worth, I experienced this same error when I had a typo (`md4` instead of `md5`) in my `pg_hba.conf` file (`/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`)

If you got here as I did, double-check that file once to make sure there isn't anything ridiculous in there.

Comment: where is the `pg_hba.conf` file?

Comment: /etc/postgresql/{postgres_version}/main/pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 1):

Just restart Postgres as soon as error appears by running `brew services restart postgresql` and then try again

Answer (score 0):

There might be different issues with running PostgreSQL locally. I would recommend to clean all versions of postgres installed and start fresh. Once you have it installed, it's very easy to recreate your database if you have your rails project with the up to date `db/schema.rb`

Here is how I usually [install PostgreSQL on a Mac](http://www.startprogrammingnowbook.com/book/setup#uid14). If you're running your database under the root user locally, you might want to omit the last step that creates a `todo` user

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason could be that

unix_socket_directories in postgresql.conf file is not listed with the directory it is looking for.

In the question example it is looking for directory /tmp this has to be provided in the postgresql.conf file

something like this:

```
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql,/tmp'    # comma-separated list of directories
```

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on MacOS and using homebrew I found this answer extremely helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708774/4062901

For me, my server was running but because of an upgrade I was having issues connecting (note: I use brew services). If Postgres is running, try `cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` and see what the logs say. My error was a migration, not a connection issue.

Also after the manual migration they propose (which does work but) I found there was no longer a table for my user. Try this command to fix that: `createdb` (answered via [psql: FATAL: database "<user>" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist))

Answer (score 0):

The following solution from a different [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307346/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections) helped me:

Find the postgres data directory. On a MAC using homebrew it is */usr/local/var/postgres/*, other systems it might be */usr/var/postgres/*

Remove pid file by running:

```
rm postmaster.pid
```

Restart postgress. On Mac, run:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score -5):

It's very simple. Only add host in your database.yaml file.

Comment: host: 127.0.0.1 or host: localhost for example.

Comment: Everyone loves a simple solution. But how does this work? As I've said in my comments above, searching on this has taken me down many a complex route. Can you elaborate somewhat and give us a bit more background as to what you see the issue really is and how this simple change addresses the issue. Thanks for contributing on this one! :)

Comment: The difference is with an IP connection there's no worrying about where the socket file is located; instead you worry about the IP address.