# Mac OSX Lion Postgres does not accept connections on /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Tags: postgresql, osx-lion, homebrew

I'm getting a common Mac OSX error for Homebrew installations of Postgres,

```
No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This is apparently due to there being multiple installs on the system.  However, the usual steps are not resolving things.

I can successfully start Postgres and running:

```
ps auxw | grep post
```

returns ..

```
euanmillar       847   0.0  0.0  2432768    588 s000  R+   11:19am   0:00.00 grep postgres
euanmillar       845   0.0  0.0  2439324    448   ??  Ss   11:19am   0:00.00 postgres:
stats collector process
euanmillar       844   0.0  0.0  2443176   1520   ??  Ss   11:19am   0:00.00 postgres:
autovacuum launcher process
euanmillar       843   0.0  0.0  2443044    544   ??  Ss   11:19am   0:00.00 postgres: wal writer process
euanmillar       842   0.0  0.0  2443044    584   ??  Ss   11:19am   0:00.00 postgres: writer process
euanmillar       841   0.0  0.0  2443044    596   ??  Ss   11:19am   0:00.00 postgres: checkpointer process
euanmillar       839   0.0  0.0  2443044   3616 s000  S    11:19am   0:00.02 /us
```

so it looks like postgres is running.

I have commented in the following lines in postgresql.conf

```
port = 5432
unix_socket_directory = '/var/pgsql_socket'
unix_socket_permissions = 0777
```

and in var/pgsql_socket/ I do have a hidden file .s.PGSQL.5432

I have tried solutions to many of the posts here. This one especially seems similar:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why

But the difference is that I do have a '/var/pgsql_socket' directory which is CHOWN-ed to everyone.  I have used Homebrew to completely remove and re-install Postgres and still I have the same issue.

Comment: The `ps` output shows that postgres is **not** running. See [another question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587) for a sample output when it's running. Your first step is to actually launch the server with the homebrew instructions.

Comment: Your description is confusing `/var/postgresql` and `/var/pgsql_socket`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and apologies if my description is a bit confusing.

Comment: I ran pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start  and I get the message "server starting" then ps auxw | grep post returns a lot of processes. But when I try to createdb I get the same socket error.

Comment: A reminder that createdb should be run as postgres user. Have you used `sudo -u postgres createdb`? Although, that might not be related to the socket issue.

Comment: Just saw that your issue has been resolved. I had used port to install most of the stuff, never tried brew! Port worked fine for me!

Comment: any of these answers suit your fancy?

Answer (score 32):

You need to remove the postmaster.pid, which should be in the following path:
`/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Answer (score 14):

For me, i removed postmaster.pid in `/usr/local/var/postgres`. fixed me right up.

Answer (score 9):

A simpler solution is to locate where the socket actually is vs where it's expected to be.  In my case, I ran:

```
$ locate PGSQL.5432
/private/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432
/private/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock
```

Then just symlink the expected socket location to the actual socket location.

```
$ ln -s /private/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Answer (score 2):

The system client is being used and not your brew version. The symlink approach only lasts until the next restart. This approach fixes the root issue I believe

1. sudo edit `/etc/paths`
2. Move the line containing `/usr/local/bin` to the top of the file. (Before `/usr/bin`)
3. Uninstall your postgres gem(s) (`gem uninstall pg`)
4. Start up new shell to load the new environment settings
5. `bundle`

Answer (score 1):

That is not an OS X specific issue. You will need to clean up your postgres installation and then reinstall it again. I have faced this issue on my ubuntu 12.04. While cleaning your previous installation, you will need to remove all packages starting with postgres (postgresql, postgresql-common, postgresql-client etc), in other words, postgres*. I have not used brew, have used port on OS X Lion. I guess the equivalent command should be `sudo brew remove postgres*`. A sudo brew install postgresql should then do the trick.

Also, if you feel the server is already running, you can try `sudo -u postgres createuser`. If that fails, you will need to reinstall.

However, the output of your `ps aux | grep post` is actually the grep command itself. Not of the postgres server running.

EDIT: Looks like the following link could be of help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why
If yes, then this question might be a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. I've followed this advice, especially the advice in the SO link and amended my initial post.  Unfortunately I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Mac Serria. In Mac Serria you can find postmaster.pid inside `/Users/<user_name>/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6` if you used GUI installer rather than homebrew.

Once you delete this file then everything should work fine.