# PG Error could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on port 5432?

Tags: ruby, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently updated my machine (MacBook Pro running Mountain Lion) and ever since then, whenever I set up a rails project, my machine craps out and cannot connect to PG. Currently, this is the error I am getting when I try to go to localhost;

> PG::ERROR could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost"
>   (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (fe80::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Here is a checklist, and list of things I have tried;

1. PostgreSQL version is 9.3.4
2. I have it installed through HomeBrew
3. I have `host: localhost` in my database.yml file
4. Rails version 4.1.1, ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.5.0]
5. Ran `brew uninstall postgresql` then `brew install postgresql`
6. Tried to access my postgres.conf file but wasn't allowed through PGAdmin and command line
7. Ran `locate pg_hba.conf` and terminal shot this out;

   ```
   WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.
   ```
8. I have also tried using rails 4.0 but I still get the problem
9. I can still work on other projects on my machine that were started/finished before I updated my computer.
10. When I run `psql` from my terminal I get
    `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

I am really lost here, and am not sure what else to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory) question, all was resolved by simply downloading **Postgres.app** for Mac. Everything works great now.

Comment: Can you connect to your PG from the console? (`psql`)?

Comment: Seems like you've verified Postgres is installed, but it needs to be running too! :)

Comment: @UriAgassi I should have added that, when I type `psql` I get; `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

Comment: @UriAgassi I was able to get it solved by downloading and using Postgres.app for Mac. Works great :)

Answer (score 23):

This is easier than you think because if you update your Mac then the process will run, but the `postmaster.pid` file is missing from `/usr/local/var/postgres/`. So you need to start process for postgres which creates postmaster.pid.

If postgres is running then:

**Stop manually:**

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

**Start manually:**

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Now all should be working.

Answer (score 23):

Run in your command line

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

If the result is like the next one

```
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf"
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 10, which is not compatible with this version 11.
```

Run

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Based in this [post](https://olivierlacan.com/posts/migrating-homebrew-postgres-to-a-new-version/)

Comment: Thank you for this. Hit the same issue after I installed an unrelated package. Homebrew updated PG and DB files became incompatible.

Comment: i had to do this when upgrading my mac to Big Sur

Answer (score 12):

if you have installed through brew

```
$ brew services stop postgresql
#adjust below  path accordingly to your machine 
$ rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid 
$ brew services start postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

For M1 systems, /usr/local/ files are moved to /opt. Hence, homebrew installs postgres at /opt/homebrew/var/postgres.

Trying to start the server manually by,

```
pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres -l /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/log start
```

Then try to check if server is running,

```
pgrep -l postgres
```

If above cmd outputs, server is running fine.
Try to find the server connection,

```
sudo find /tmp/ -name .s.PGSQL.5432
```

Then connect to db by,

```
psql -h /tmp/ databaseName
```