# Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Before anything, please note that I have found several similar questions on Stack Overflow and articles all over the web, but none of those helped me fix my issue:

- [PG Error could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on port 5432?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333317/pg-error-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused-is-the-server-running-o)
- [PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828385/pgconnectionbad-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-refused)
- [psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused](https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/37)

Now, here is the issue:

- I have a Rails app that works like a charm.
- With my collaborator, we use GitHub to work together.
- We have a `master` and an `mvp` branches.
- I recently updated my `git` version with Homebrew (Mac).
- We use Foreman to start our app locally.

Now, when I try to launch the app locally, I get the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad at /
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried to reboot my computers several times.

I also checked the content of `/usr/local/var/postgres`:

```
PG_VERSION      pg_dynshmem     pg_multixact    pg_snapshots    pg_tblspc       postgresql.conf
base            pg_hba.conf     pg_notify       pg_stat         pg_twophase     postmaster.opts
global          pg_ident.conf   pg_replslot     pg_stat_tmp     pg_xlog         server.log
pg_clog         pg_logical      pg_serial       pg_subtrans     postgresql.auto.conf
```

As you can see, there is no `postmaster.pid` file in there.

Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Can you update the question with the content of `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: I know this is a very old question. But today I faced the same problem in Mac and `brew reinstall postgresql@13` resolved the problem for me. (It is a requirement to use v13 for my project)

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163070/14591547

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You most likely ran out of battery and your postgresql server didn't shutdown correctly.

The easiest workaround is to download the official postgresql app and launch it: it will force the server to start (http://postgresapp.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just downloaded the app and launched it. If I shut it down before launching my server, then I still get the same error. If I don't shut it down, then I get an error message stating that my "database does not exist". Can this be related?

Comment: If your database does not exist, you should run rake db:create .
But this is most likely not related ... Did you just fork a repo or something like this ? You shouldn't shut it down before launching your server using 'rails s' !! The app has to be running the whole time you want to access your site on a localhost

Comment: Ok. No, I did not fork a repo, it is the same repo I was working with. But I ran `git fetch`, maybe this is the problem.

Comment: git fetch is not supposed to be deleting the database. What's happening if you run rake db:create ?

Comment: "Ran out of battery"... this is exactly what happened! :-O

Comment: With this error the other client application 'pgAdmin'did not run the server nor used the 5432 port. But fixed it by reinstalling PostgreSQL DBMS.

Comment: It just started doing this when I downloaded it the very first time. Your solution tho is 100% working and fixed it

Comment: thank you so much. after so much search this ended up fixing my issue

Answer (score 193):

run  `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` and you should see something like:

```
 FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
 HINT:   Is another postmaster (PID 379) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

Then run `kill -9 PID` in HINT

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Best solution for my case, which is that my machine shut down unexpectedly and restarting the service was not solving the issue - thanks!

Comment: If you're using homebrew, `brew services start postgres` or `brew services restart postgres` might do the trick

Comment: thank you! I ran with this issue for the second time, how did you understand that this would be the solution?

Comment: Any equivalent solution for linux ubuntu dist?

Comment: This worked for me when nothing else on the internet did. My machine did shut down unexpectedly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Best solution for my case, which is that my machine shut down unexpectedly and restarting the service was not solving the issue - thanks!

Comment: We are  in dec 2020 and this solution work for me after a long time of research. thanks a lot

Comment: No such file or directory

Comment: Where do I locate this file on windows?

Answer (score 77):

Most likely it's because your system shutdown unexpectedly

Try

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

You might see

> ```
> FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
> HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 449) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
> ```

Then try

```
kill -9 PID
```

example

```
kill -9 419
```

And it should start postgres normally

Comment: Yes my system shut down unexpectedly and this solved my problem. thank you.

Answer (score 41):

The postgresql server might be down and the solution might be as simple as running:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

which fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 32):

This could be caused by the pid file created for postgres which has not been deleted due to unexpected shutdown. To fix this, remove this pid file.

1. Find the postgres data directory. On a MAC using homebrew it is `/usr/local/var/postgres/`, other systems it might be `/usr/var/postgres/`
2. Remove pid file by running:

   ```
   rm postmaster.pid
   ```
3. Restart postgress. On Mac, run:

   ```
   brew services restart postgresql
   ```

Comment: Thx! Personally I had to remove in this way:
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var-<versionId>/postmaster.pid

Comment: What is the cause of this?  I never had these types of issues with MySql?

Answer (score 18):

I had almost just as same error with my Ruby on Rails application running postgresql(mac). This worked for me:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 16):

This worked in my case:

```
brew uninstall postgresql
rm -fr /usr/local/var/postgres/
brew install postgresql
```

Comment: these installation paths are darn confusing. Finally, this one worked. Removing the previous installation files was the solution.

Answer (score 8):

1. In my case PostgreSQL updates from version `13.4` to `14` in background, so it fixes by:

   ```
   brew postgresql-upgrade-database
   ```
2. In other case the problem fixed by:

   ```
   rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
   ```

   or

   ```
   rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
   ```

   or by version (for example `postgresql@14`)

   ```
   rm /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14/postmaster.pid
   ```
3. Restart service `postgresql`:

   ```
   brew services restart postgresql
   ```

PS:

**How can you understand** what is the problem?

**For first** see what service is not correct started:

```
brew services list
```

**For second** show file `postgres.log`, where will be the error:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log
```

or

```
tail -f /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgres*
```

**And so** find answer by this error's text

Answer (score 6):

Step 1:

```
cd /etc/postgresql/12/main/
```

open file named `postgresql.conf`

```
sudo nano postgresql.conf
```

add this line to that file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

then open file named `pg_hba.conf`

```
sudo nano pg_hba.conf
```

and add this line to that file

```
host  all  all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

It allows access to all databases for all users with an encrypted password

**restart your server**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the issue via this command

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

At times, you might get this error

```
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
```

So, try running the following command and then run the first command given above.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem when I was trying to connect my **Django** application to **PostgreSQL** database.

I wrote my `Dockerfile` with instructions to setup the **Django** project followed by instructions to install **PostgreSQL** and run **Django** server in my `docker-compose.yml`.

I defined two services in my `docker-compose-yml`.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=abc
      - POSTGRES_USER=abc
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=abc
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  django:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8004
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 8004:8004
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Unfortunately whenever I used to run `docker-compose up` then same err. used to pop up.

And this is how my database was defined in **Django** `settings.py`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'abc',
        'USER': 'abc',
        'PASSWORD': 'abc',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
        },
    }
}
```

So, In the end I made use of `docker-compose` [networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) which means if I change the `host` of my database to `postgres` which is defined as a service in `docker-compose.yml` will do the wonders.

So, Replacing `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'` **=>**   `'HOST': 'postgres'` did wonders for me.

After replacement this is how your Database config in `settings.py` will look like.

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'abc',
            'USER': 'abc',
            'PASSWORD': 'abc',
            'HOST': 'postgres',
            'PORT': '5432',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
            },
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to restart Postgresql on Linux, then you have to use the following command.

`/etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved my problem:

see the status of services

```
brew services list
```

and the output was :

```
Name       Status  User Plist
postgresql error   myuser /Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
unbound    stopped
```

I change the file name in this path, you can also remove it

```
mv /Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist /Users/myuser/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist_temp
```

and then reboot the os

```
sudo reboot
```

after booting I started the `postgresql` and it worked.

```
brew services start postgresql
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I have a deadline to submit my work and I got this error due to improper shutdown. You saved my day!!

Answer (score 3):

1. Find postgresql@10 service directory

```
  $ ls /usr/local/var/postgresql@10
```

[image]

2. Find file `postmaster.pid` and delete that file

```
  $ rm -f postmaster.pid
```

3. Restart postgres service using

```
  $ brew services restart postgresql@10
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:
run

`sudo lsof -i :<port_number>`

after that it will display the PID which is currently attached to the process.

After that run `sudo kill -9 <PID>`

if that doesn't work,
try the solution offered by user8376606 it would definitely work!

Answer (score 2):

In my case

1. I have changed the port in postgresql.conf file
2. and restart postgresql services in

Run => service.msc => Restart

3. now retry

Answer (score 1):

First I tried

> lsof -wni tcp:5432
>   but it doesn't show any PID number.

Second I tried

> Postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
>   and it showed that server is listening.

So I just restarted my mac to restore all ports back and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For **Docker** users: In my case it was caused by excessive docker image size. You can remove unused data using `prune` command:

```
docker system prune --all --force --volumes
```

**Warning:** as per manual (`docker system prune --help`):

> This will remove:
>
> - all stopped containers
> - all networks not used by at least one container
> - all dangling images
> - all dangling build cache

Answer (score 1):

For me, the answer provided by @DivyanshuRawat's looks more like the real solution to this error.

As of this day; the 15th of March 2023 in my Django App, I experienced the same problem. And when I saw @DivyanshuRawat's answer, I tried it and it didn't work for me. I believe the reason it didn't work for me may have been the way he explained which sucessfully befuddled me, or my own impatience due to mental saturation. However, given what I know now, I wonder why it wasn't upvoted a lot given the fact that it made sense.

In my submission here, I will try to explain @DivyanshuRawat's answer a bit further, hopefully it can be clear to others facing the same problem and looking into answers here for leads to solving the error.

You need to note that;

1. `this error usually occurs when the networks section in your Docker Compose file is not formatted correctly.`
2. `the error simply tells you that the service is unable to connect to the PostgreSQL database running in your docker database service, mostly because the hostname in your Django settings.py file is pointing to the web service container itself or something/somewhere else, rather than the docker database service container where the database is running.`

Fixing this error;

1. You have to make sure that `networks` section is defined at the top level of your Compose file, outside of any services, volumes, or other sections. Also ensure that it is formatted as a `mapping`, where each network is listed with a unique name, followed by its configuration options. This example below shows how the networks section should be formatted and this is the first thing I had to make sure I fix in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

   ```
   version: '3.9'

   services:
     web:
       # ...service configuration

       networks:
        - webnet

     db:
       # ....service configuration

       networks:
        - webnet

   networks:
     webnet:
       driver: bridge
   ```
2. Changing the "HOST" parameter in your DATABASES setting in settings.py to the name of the db service container (which in this case is "db"), like this:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
           'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
           'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
           'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
           'HOST': 'db', # change it to your docker-compose postgres service name. If you look at my own docker-compose.yml file, it is defined as 'db', so I changed this HOST config to 'db'
           'PORT': '5432',
       }
   }
   ```

After making the necessary changes, you can try rebuilding and running your docker containers with `docker-compose up --build` to see if it resolves the issue. At this point, everything worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I often encounter this problem on windows,the way I solved the problem is Service - Click PostgreSQL Database Server 8.3 -  Click the second tab "log in" - choose the first line "the local system account".

Answer (score 0):

It also gives the same error if you just stop your PostgreSQL app. You just need to start it again. (PostgreSQL 11)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I was unable to start the postgresql server and was unable to access my db even after giving password, and I have been doing all the possible ways.

This solution worked for me,

For the Ubuntu users:
Through command line, type the following commands:

1.service --status-all (which gives list of all services and their status. where "+" refers to running and "-" refers that the service is no longer running)

check for postgresql status, if its "-" then type the following command

2.systemctl start postgresql (starts the server again)

**refresh the postgresql page in browser, and it works**

For the Windows users:

Search for services, where we can see list of services and the right click on postgresql, click on start and server works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to change the database from postgres (on my production) back to sqlite3 which I was using for development.

Answer (score 0):

### **It's working for me** >>Node.Js App

user@MacBook-Pro % sudo lsof -i :5430

**Output**

COMMAND  PID           user  FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

node    7885 user   21u  IPv6 0x2e7d89f6118f95b9      0t0  TCP *:radec-corp (LISTEN)

**Kill the PID**

user@MacBook-Pro % sudo kill -9 7885

**One more test**

user@MacBook-Pro % sudo lsof -i :5430

user@MacBook-Pro % **"No more running PID for the port 5430"**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, on a Ruby on Rails project, I removed a .pid file from the folder `tmp/pids` and restart the system.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I checked that my database.yml file, (dev mode) host was pointing to 5433. I updated it to 5432 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs this for `windows`, read on.

On windows hit the `Windows button` + `R`
then enter `services.msc` and look for `postgresql-x64-14`, Right click it and click `start`

Then go back to your `PgAdmin4` for windows and then enter your `master password` if asked.
From here, you should be able to proceed as usual with viewing of the db schemas.

Also, for Django, restart your server with `CTR+C` then `python manage.py runserver` (assuming you're working inside a virtual env)

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef|grep postgres
```

Then kill the process with PID

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Then start the postgresql

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case I when it happens to me I need to do the following steps:

**1º Step**

Log in `postgres` user:
`#sudo su postgres`

**2º Step**

Run the following steps: `/opt/PostgreSQL/10/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/10/data -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

*Explanation:*

We access the utility of postgres located at `/opt/PostgreSQL/10/bin/` in your case could be another but identify where it's.

After this step we tell to the utility of postgres where the it's data folder is by using the option -D, this data folder contains all necessary configuration of postgres server.

The option -r we tell to postgres where to send `stdout` and `stderr` to given file, in my case the file that I used is `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

*Note:*

- I'm using Postgre 10
- Linux Ubuntu