# Why does Phoenix (ecto/Postgresx) fail to Connect in dev

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, boxen

I am beginning my Elixir/Phoenix journey and having some trouble with my postgres connection.

When I start up my server I get:

```
 $ mix phoenix.server
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.214.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.217.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.218.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.211.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.215.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.219.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.216.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.213.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.212.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.210.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
 [info] Running Rumbl.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://localhost:4000
 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.215.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
```

Being new to Elixir, Phoenix, and Ecto I am unclear how to debug this problem. Any suggestions as to what my problem is or how I might go about debugging it would be much appreciated.

**My app's set up**

I have a basic app

```
mix phoenix.new rumbl
cd rumbl
mix deps.get
mix deps.compile
```

My config/dev.exs has the following db setup

```
# Configure your database
config :rumbl, Rumbl.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "elixir",
  database: "rumbl_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

When I run `mix ecto.create` there are no errors and I can see the `rumbl_dev` when I run `\l` in psql. It is owned by the elixir user too.

Running `mix ecto.migrate` throws the same connections errors

My pg_hba.conf file has the following

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Here is what I see when I log in with psql

```
$ psql --dbname=rumbl_dev --username=elixir --host=127.0.0.1 --password
Password for user elixir:
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

rumbl_dev=>
```

Comment: Can you try adding the password to the config and see if that helps. ```config :rumbl, Rumbl.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "elixir",
  database: "rumbl_dev",
  hostname: "localhost", password: "***password***"
  pool_size: 10```

Comment: I tried that too but get the same results - thanks for the suggestion @stephen_m

Comment: can you try running the following command from the terminal:  ```psql --dbname=rumbl_dev --username=elixir --host=127.0.0.1 --password```

Comment: `hostname: "localhost"` ⇒ `hostname: "127.0.0.1"` might help.

Comment: @stephen_m I appended the result of that to my question. It lets me in no problem.

Comment: @mudasobwa I had tried that but same result

Comment: After all, do you have `{:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"}, {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}` in your `mix.exs`’ deps?

Comment: is this line somewhere in your `config/dev.exs`? --- ```config :rumbl, ecto_repos: [Rumbl.Repo]```, if not can you add it and try ecto migration then?

Comment: @stephen_m that was in my `config/config.exs` file but I tried it in `config/dev.exs` also but got the same result unfortunately

Comment: @mudasobwa my `mix.exs` has exactly those in the lock they come through as `"postgrex": {:hex, :postgrex, "0.11.2", ...}` and `"phoenix_ecto": {:hex, :phoenix_ecto, "3.0.1", ...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out. It is a simple mistake on my part in the end. Though an easy one to make.

I am using Boxen on my Mac and it changes the port to `15432` for some reason.

I may have landed on this sooner if the `mix ecto.create` had failed. Not sure why that works.

Hopefully this will help others in the future

Comment: glad it worked. don't know why ```mix ecto.create``` part works though. you could check it on the console too for the port ```psql --dbname=rumbl_dev --username=elixir --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 --password```

Comment: @stephen_m - it does not work on the console with port=5432. It is odd that the create works.

Comment: great! thanks so much, I'm using boxen as well. specifying `port: 15432` on `config.dev.ex`s solved it.

Answer (score 19):

This happened to me twice, after **macOS** crashed.

Most recently I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45352573/1678614):

#### Fix 1

1. Run `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`
2. Copy the number after `PID` if you see something like this:

   ```
   FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists 
   HINT:   Is another postmaster (PID 379) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
   ```
3. `kill -9 PID` with the process # in place of `PID`.

---

The [steps](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18760#issuecomment-410533581) that worked for me previously:

#### Fix 2

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

Comment: Fix 1 worked for me (after macOS crashed). Thank you.

Comment: Same here. My macOS crashed. Seems to be happening more recently. Came back to postgres giving the same problem and this Fix 1 fixed it for me. The accepted answer seems like a different issue.

Answer (score 2):

- Delete the database `rumbl_dev` in postgresql to make a fresh start.
- If you like, you can try md5 auth for the dev version on localhost by adding the following line to the *pg_hba.conf*

  ```
  # host DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD

  host rumbl_dev elixir localhost md5
  ```

  *Note:* See here for more on setting up the [/etc/postsgresql/9.4/pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and change the settings as you see fit.
- Add the complete settings with password to `dev.exs`:

  ```
  config :rumbl, Rumbl.Repo, 
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres, 
  username: "elixir", 
  database: "rumbl_dev", 
  hostname: "localhost", 
  password: "***password***",
  pool_size: 10
  ```
- Try running `mix do ecto.create, ecto.migrate` and see how it goes.

Hope this helps, if not, I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: same result I am afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your database user's password within your config block.

```
config :rumbl, Rumbl.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: "elixir",
  password: "???",
  database: "rumbl_dev",
  hostname: "localhost",
  pool_size: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem every time I don't start Postgres before calling `mix phoenix.server`. I use https://postgresapp.com to kick it off.