# Docker Compose Django + PostgreSQL access postgres host without using service name

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

So, basically i have this `docker-compose.yml` config:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: youtube_manager_postgres
    restart: always
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty123
      - POSTGRES_DB=ytmanager
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  django:
    container_name: youtube_manager_django
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: deploy/django/Dockerfile
    command: sh -c "poetry run python3 manage.py migrate &&
                    poetry run python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear &&
                    poetry run uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi.ini"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/code/static
      - mediafiles:/code/media
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

My Django's database preferences are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ytmanager',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        'PASSWORD': 'qwerty123',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I wan't to use it in two ways:
1. Running `docker-compose up -d postgres` and then `python3 manage.py runserver` (actually, `poetry run python3 manage.py runserver` but for now it doesn't matter) during development.
2. Running `docker-compose up` during deployment.

For now, it works fine with the 1 option, but when I'm execution `docker-compose up` I'm getting an error:

```
youtube_manager_django | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
youtube_manager_django |        Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
youtube_manager_django |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

If I'm changing Django database settings this way:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ytmanager',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        'PASSWORD': 'qwerty123',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Executing `docker-compose up -d postgres` and then `python manage.py runserver` causes an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

How could I properly config `docker-compose.yml` to use the same `HOST` in Django settings? (for example, `'HOST': '0.0.0.0'` or `'HOST': 'postgres'` for both options).

I've tried to use `network_mode: host` on my django and postgres services. It works fine, but is there any other way to solve a problem (for example, using networking settings? I've read docker-compose documentation on their website, but can't get what's going on there).

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; you wouldn't usually use it as the `HOST` setting you show.  The Docker and non-Docker environments are different and you will need different `HOST` settings; an environment variable is a typical approach (default it to `localhost` for non-Docker but provide the alternate value in the `docker-compose.yml` file).

Comment: Can I use `0.0.0.0` adress for both django and postgres services?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing develop a production environments (by the way, second time you pasted your Django database settings probably you meant `'HOST': 'postgres'`)

So, if I'm not wrong:

1. On development you want in your Django setting .py file: `'HOST': '0.0.0.0'`, since i think your are
   executing `python manage.py runserver` outside docker,
   keeping postgres in docker.
2. On production you want the same in your Django setting .py file: `'HOST': '0.0.0.0'`, but to make it work you need `'HOST': 'postgres'` (matching the name of the service in the compose file) and run everything on docker (executing the whole compose file as it is: `docker-compose up`). In this case, Django can't get access to `'0.0.0.0'` database host since it is running 'containerized' and that ip don't bind to any service, so it needs the ip or name of the service `'postgres'`.

### Posible solution:

In my opinion the solution is having two yml files to be called by Docker ( e.g. `docker-compose -f docker-compose-development.yml up`):

- docker-compose-development.yml
- docker-compose-production.yml

In each .yml file you can use different env variables or settings to cover differences between development and production in a clean way.

You can have a look at:
https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django. It is a template Django project using Docker.

It follows "The Twelve Factors" app methodology:
https://12factor.net/

In short:

1. Environment variables are set in files under the .envs folder.
2. in the compose .yml files you point to them in order to load the environment variables:

```
env_file:
     ./.envs/.production/.postgres
```

3. Django settings .py files get access to the env variables using the django-environ package.

Answer (score 0):

Before editing Django DB config, please ensure the following:

- Both containers are running in the same network.
- Postgres service is up and running in the container.
- Service 'postgres' is accessible from the webapp container. For this you can login to the container and perform a ping test.
  `docker exec -it containerID /bin/bash (in some cases /bin/sh) # to login to container`

Solutions:

1. Similar:
   [Django connection to postgres by docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811727/django-connection-to-postgres-by-docker-compose)
2. For you to connect to DB using service name in Django, as per the documentation **if the HOST and PORT keys are left out of the dictionary then Django will try connecting with the complete "NAME" as a SID**.

Hope it helps