# could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host ... and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have just deployed a Postgres / timescaleDB on Ubuntu in AWS.

When I ssh my postgres VM, I can connect pgsql via CLI.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-57:~$ psql -U julien -h localhost db
Password for user julien: 
psql (12.3 (Ubuntu 12.3-1.pgdg20.04+1))
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

db=>
```

I can also see postgres is listening

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-57:~$ sudo netstat -nlpute
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        46086      6152/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20033      700/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      113        62083      20332/postgres      
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          68924      23549/apache2       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          20044      700/sshd: /usr/sbin 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           101        46085      6152/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 172.31.35.57:68         0.0.0.0:*                           100        651337     6134/systemd-networ
```

I checked ufw:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-57:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I also opened fully Security Groups.

But still, I cannot connect my postgres DB from local.

With a local Postgres DB, I have no problem ( my app works )

What did I forget ???

Comment: It may be silly to ask... but are you running them as docker?

Comment: no, I don't....

Comment: You are listening to 5432 only on the localhost (127.0.0.1) interface.  You need to change `listen_addresses` in your `postgresql.conf` file.

Comment: Follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74163070/14591547

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check listen_addresses in postgresql.conf file allowed remote connections. It should be

   listen_addresses = '*'
2. In pg_hba.conf file you need to add following entry

   host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
3. Be sure it is not a firewall issue.

Comment: if it is a firewall issue, what shall I do? how to check and how to fix?? please let me know.. because I did change all, pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf like you said above but still get same problem.

Comment: @PeterKam in this case you shoud add the port 5432 to your firewall like this : sudo ufw allow 5432