# How can I link two Docker containers together? One is a MySQL container hosting the database, and the other is a Python flask application

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy

I am attempting to build a bridge between my flask application and my database using two separate containers rather than the mysql connector.
I am using flask_mysqldb for my app.

```
  ---docker-compose
     App
      |
      |--app.py
      |--dockerfile
     db
      |
      |--dockerfile
      |--db.sql
```

**This is My Docker-compose file**

```
  version: '2'
  services:
    pythonapp:
        build: ./NewtestPythonProject
        command: sh -c "sleep 10s ; python3 ./main.py"
        ports:
        - '5000:5000'
        depends_on:
          - mysql
        
          
    mysql:
      build: ./MyDbDockerFile
      restart: always
      environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'profile'
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1234'
      ports:
        - '3306:3306'
```

**This is my Database Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:latest
COPY ./dcs.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**This is my app dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /usr/app/src

COPY . /usr/app/src/

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 5000
```

**This is My Connection String**

```
from flask import *
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import yaml,re 
import MySQLdb.cursors
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'This'
#-----------------------------database connection-----------
db = yaml.load(open("db.yaml"),Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] =  db['mysql_host']
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] =  db['mysql_user']
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] =  db['mysql_password']
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] =  db['mysql_db']

MySQL = MySQL(app)
```

**Db.yaml**

```
mysql_host: "localhost"
mysql_user: "root"
mysql_password: "1234"
mysql_db: "profile"
```

Comment: What's the question ? From your python webapp can you reach mysql:3306 ?

Comment: @0x0fba is i am able to reach  mysql:3306,  but I'm having trouble connecting my app and database container.

Comment: What kind of trouble ? Can your webapp connect to your db ?
Use `docker logs` can help troubleshooting.

Comment: My Webapp Container is unable to connect to my MySQL Docker Container, however everything is working properly in my local environment. I can't get my two containers to communicate with one another.

Comment: You can try to update docker-compose to version 3.
And to read the log of your containers.

Comment: Isn't [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) required?

Comment: I would say that `links` isn't required anymore since docker-compose `v2`.

Comment: `links:` is obsolete and you should delete it.

Comment: @user9778557 You've said a couple of times that the application database connection doesn't work.  Can you [edit] the question to include the details of that connection and the actual error you're getting?  What you've shown so far seems fine.

Comment: I have updated the same as you have requested @DavidMaze

Comment: `mysql_host: "localhost"` tells your Flask container to connect to itself, not the separate database container.  See among other things [Django connection to postgres by docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811727/django-connection-to-postgres-by-docker-compose).

Comment: When you have a problem, you have to show the logs. How are others supposed to help you without an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Change in `Db.yaml` the line `mysql_host: "localhost"` to `mysql_host: "mysql"` because the localhost is the same container.

Comment: @user9778557 your problem was fixed? if my answer is correct, please confirm this with the check