# Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?&

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, superuser

I am trying to create a superuser via: 
`sudo docker-compose up` 
`python3 manage.py createsuper user`

In a minute i get this:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "8500" (0.0.33.52), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`

Next, I check if my containers are running:
`sudo docker-compose ps`
And i get:

```
NAME                IMAGE               COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
credo1-db-1         postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   db                  6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8500->5432/tcp, :::8500->5432/tcp
credo1-web-1        credo1-web          "python manage.py ru…"   web                 6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp
```

**In my settings:**

```
default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'clothing_store',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD':  'postgres',
    'HOST': 8500,  
    'PORT': 5432,  
}
```

}

**docker-compose:**

```
    version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=clothing_store
    ports:
      - "8500:5432"

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

volumes:
postgres_data:

I am trying to create a superuser via:
`sudo docker-compose up`
`python3 manage.py createsuper user`

Comment: `'HOST': 8500` isn't meaningful; the numeric value is being interpreted as a low-level representation of an IPv4 address.  Also see for example [Django connection to postgres by docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811727/django-connection-to-postgres-by-docker-compose), or [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation, for more information about connecting between containers.