# Could not connect to server: Connection refused from both port 5432 and 54320 depends on what I'm doing

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm doing a laravel project, when migrate with port 5432 it shows me could not connect error so I change to port 54320 in .env file. Everything seems okay till I make some test query and Homestead.test/api/test displays could not connect error again. Switch back to 5432 and everything is okay. I can only migrate or seed with port 54320 and make some api query with 5432.
Here is my .env file.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=54320
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: are you running "php artisan config:cache" after each changes in .env ??

Comment: yes I have tried that with no result. Every time I use config:cache I have to route:clear, config:clear and cache:clear or I will get protocol error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing port forwarding from

54320(host) => 5432(guest) to 5432(host) => 5432(guest)

in Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager. Have no idea why default settings not working in the first place, but at least I no longer need to flip port back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

Set these 2 environment variables like this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

Run this for refreshing the env config:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And try again. If you'll get an error, then we'll think about that.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but now I got 2 errors `Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432` + `Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432`. Sorry I'm new here and have no idea how to format comment.

Comment: Ok, then 1. comment/remove the DB_PORT line from .env, 2. In the "config/databases.php" make sure you have this    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),   inside of 'pgsql' array. 3. run "php artisan config:cache" 4. retry again.... I think this will solve the problem

Comment: I'm sorry, tried it and still got the same errors. It's weird that I can still run migration fine with port 54320.

Comment: Are you using Docker?? By the way, please check your local IP like this
    ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'    or like this     curl -4 icanhazip.com    or with       ipconfig       And paste that IP as your DB_HOST   Run "php artisan config:cache" and retry

Comment: No I'm using laravel with homestead on windows 10. I tried all ip addresses found in ipconfig, 1 local and 2 virtualbox, each showing same error checking if that address is accepting connection on port 5432.

Comment: Then I think the reason comes from your Postgres. May something wrong with it. So follow to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307346/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections#answer-37307420) for similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, this can also be caused by our dear friend, SELinux.

These steps got it working for me:

- Enable TCP/IP connections for httpd

  ```sh
  setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
  setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
  ```
- (Optional) Allow httpd access to home directories

  ```sh
  setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
  ```
- Set SELinux context for files being served

  ```sh
  chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /path/to/web/files
  ```
- Give httpd rw access to Laravel's storage directory

  ```sh
  chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /path/to/web/files/storage
  ```

#### References

- [Apache and SELinux](https://beginlinux.com/server_training/web-server/976-apache-and-selinux)
- [httpd_sys_rw_contexnt_t](https://serverfault.com/a/626611)