# Django can not connect to PostgreSQL DB

Tags: django, postgresql

When I`m trying to connect Django Server to PostgreSQL db there is an error:
" port 5433 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? "

I`m using Windows 10, Pycharm, Debian

Settings in Django:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'ps_store_db',
        'USER': 'zesshi',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}
```

Tried to check connection with DBeaver and all`s good there, but still cant connect with Django

My firewall is off, i was trying to change from 5432 to 5433

[Dbeaver connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4vd6.png)

[Dbeaver connection 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWkb3.png)

Comment: Are you connecting from the same machine with Django as with DBeaver?

Comment: Yes with the same machine

Comment: Then how does Windows and Debian enter into this? Are you dealing with virtual machines? Add information as update to question.

Comment: Your dbeaver screen shot has a uninformative dialog box obscuring some of the important parts of the thing behind it.  well, I think it does: not speaking that language makes it hard to know for sure.

Comment: i will update my screenshot

Comment: Updated screens

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting/reinstalling postgres. Most likely DBeaver has blocked the port that's why you are not able to connect from django.
(Sorry for posting answer, i am unable to comment yet)

Comment: This is a useless comment and/or answer. DBeaver has nothing to do with the port that the Postgres server is listening on, it just another client like Django.

Comment: I might be wrong but this looks like a similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307346/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections

Comment: That question and answer have nothing to do with DBeaver, it is a server issue.

Comment: I download DBeaver after this problem to check if connection is normal

Comment: Go inside bin folder in C drive where Postgres is installed. run following command in git bash or Command prompt:

`pg_ctl.exe restart -D "<path upto data>"`

Ex:

`pg_ctl.exe restart -D  "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data"`

Another way: type "services.msc" in run popup(windows + R). This will show all services running Select Postgres service from list and click on start/stop/restart.

Comment: I tried this way as well mate, restarting still cant help

Answer (score 0):

The default port of the PG database is 5432. If you need to change this port, you need to edit the postgresql.conf file and restart the database service before the client can access it.
You also need to check the pg_hba.conf file. The recommended configuration is as follows:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

Comment: I would not call that a recommended configuration as that opens the server to connections from anywhere to any database in the cluster and from any database user  and that is dangerous.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver IP and database can be fixed for finer access control