# Error executing a github code last modified on January 10, 2023

Tags: python-3.x, vue.js, flask, socket.io, ubuntu-22.04

I am making a private messenger using Flask. This Github [code](https://github.com/Onroe/FlaskChat) is of interest.  Executing `flask run` on command line, Ubuntu 22.04, as instructed on the "README.md" on Github page, the computer returns the following error:

```
    ImportError: cannot import name 'escape' from 'jinja2' (/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py)
```

The "requirements.txt" file installed using "pip3 install -r requirements.txt" is as follows:

```
Flask_SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
Flask_JWT_Extended==3.24.1
Flask_SocketIO==4.2.1
Flask_RESTful==0.3.8
Flask_Migrate==2.5.3
Flask==1.1.1
Flask_Cors==3.0.8
Werkzeug==0.15.4
SQLAlchemy==1.3.5
```

Kindly help.

I followed the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718167/importerror-cannot-import-name-escape-from-jinja2). It did not work.

=================================================================

The above part was solved on 3rd November, 2023, using the answer below by AKX.

==================================================================

Following the instructions on `README.md`, both the `flask run` and `npm run serve` now run fine. The database part is confusing on `README.md`. My attempt and error are as follows:

```
$ python3
Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from database import init_db
>>> init_db()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2262, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 138, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 154, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 451, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/home/Documents/doctor_jha/flask/FlaskChat/api/database.py", line 15, in init_db
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4286, in create_all
    bind._run_visitor(
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2032, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 135, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2024, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self._contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2226, in _contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2265, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1536, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 399, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2262, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 363, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 760, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 492, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 138, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 154, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 136, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 308, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 437, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 639, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 114, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 451, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/home/home/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>>>
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307346/is-the-server-running-on-host-localhost-1-and-accepting-tcp-ip-connections) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942485/psql-fatal-ident-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres), but didn't work.

Kindly help.

Comment: If you followed the instructions given there, how does your `requirements.txt` look like now?

Comment: Excuse me. Kindly look at the updated code. This is the original `requirements.txt` file on github. Still getting the same error on executing `flask run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That repository does not properly lock transitive dependencies, so you've ended up installing a [too-recent version of Jinja2 that doesn't export `escape`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/changes/#version-3-1-0, https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/1544).

Install an older version of Jinja, and a compatible version of its dependency MarkupSafe too:

```
pip install "jinja2<3.0" "markupsafe<2.0"
```

Comment: Thank you. It did take me a step further. Out of curiosity, in your solution, should it be `pip` or `pip3`? I used `pip` as you instructed.

Comment: Depends on your system configuration. Within a virtualenv, both will do.