# Homebrew postgres broken

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I installed Postgresql 9.4.0 installed on my Mac (10.10.1/Yosemite) using homebrew. It does not work.

I have created the softlink to /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents.

If I try to manually load postgres I get the message that the "Operation is in progress"

```
> launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Operation already in progress
```

However postgres does not appear to be running.

```
> ps auxw | grep post
billmcn           670   0.0  0.0  2424272    452 s000  R+   10:12PM   0:00.01 grep post
```

and I cannot connect with the command line client.

```
> psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

To my knowledge I have tried all the fixes suggested on [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server) [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory) threads discussing this problem. Specifically:

- I have uninstalled and reinstalled postgres and the accompanying Ruby gem. There is no postgres 8.0 version on my machine.
- I have verified that the psql client program is the 9.4.0 version installed by Homebrew and not a Mac system binary.
- I have verified that the /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid does not exist.
- I have rebooted the machine.

I did have Homebrew postgres working on this machine earlier. I think what broke it is upgrading from version 8 to version 9 but I'm not sure.

I don't have any databases I need to preserve. I'm willing to start clean with postgres; I just need to get it to work now. Any ideas?

---

The issue appears to have been permissions on the /usr/local/var/postgres directory. Here is what my var directory looked like when things weren't working.

```
ll /usr/local/var/
drwxr-xr-x  3 billmcn  admin  102 Dec 20 12:44 cache
drwxr--r--  2 root     admin   68 Dec 29 21:37 postgres
```

(whoami = "billmcn")

I deleted /usr/local/var/postgres, uninstalled and reinstalled postgres, and now it looks like this.

```
ll /usr/local/var/
drwxr-xr-x   3 billmcn  admin  102 Dec 20 12:44 cache
drwx------  23 billmcn  admin  782 Dec 30 10:51 postgres
```

Not sure how it got into this state because I don't remember futzing with the permissions on this directory, but no matter. It works now.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I had the same problem installing postgres using homebrew on a freshly installed Yosemite.

First off my brew config looks like this:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 9f6926265f8e4be7cc80dfe9042f2cd3c1e8dc9e
Last commit: 64 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.10.1-x86_64
Xcode: 6.1.1
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 2.0.0-481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
```

First thing i noticed was that I had no write permission to `/usr/local/var/postgres`. This was easily changed issuing `` sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/var/postgres `` then I reinstalled postgresql and did

`cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`

which revealed:

`postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory`

So I removed the directory `/usr/local/var/postgres` and issued the command to initialize the database.

`initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres/`

This seemed to have done the trick and postgres is running fine.

Comment: I followed these steps but upon executing the initdb command I get: "could not access directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Permission denied." Again, this is after the steps you list, including deleting that directory directly before running initd.

Comment: The system normally don't lie on these things. If you do a "ls -l /usr/local/var | grep postgres" is your user set as owner of the directory ?

Comment: I just gave up and switched to macports before I saw your comment. And, it's working just fine now.

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much. I'm struggling with this since 2 hours. I thought that Homebrew should have simplified that installation.

Comment: I wish I could +5 this.

Comment: initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Operation not permitted

Comment: sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/var/postgres, then initdb.

Comment: Strangely enough, these steps work. I had done small variation of these steps (i.e., sudo chown and initdb; without reinstalling postgresql in between) and that hadn't worked. Very strange.

Comment: Second time I'm running into this issue after upgrading the OS - it would be really great, if brew postgres could handle this automatically

Comment: ```sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/var/postgres``` did the trick for me, thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem on High Sierra. The solution worked

Comment: awesome, thanks...

I have difficulty when running in the new postgres version 13 from 12

this helps me

Comment: This worked for me. For some reason I was completely missing the `/usr/local/var` directory (after having postgres working fine for months). Recreated the var folder with `sudo mkdir /usr/local/var` ran the sudo chown command on it, then reran the `initdb` fn mentioned above. Then had to recreate the initial user ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist)) and now I'm good

Answer (score 67):

I had this same problem.  The primary issue here is that the initdb step of installation will create the directory with root ownership instead of as the user on a Mac.  To solve this issue:

Create the data directory before running `initdb` and set permissions of 0700

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres  # in case this is not your first try
mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres
chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Then run `initdb` and it will respect the permissions of the data directory.

```
initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

For grins and giggles, create a test db named after your user:

```
createdb `whoami`
```

Login to test:

```
psql
```

Comment: I go to `rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres` and or `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres` and both seemingly delete the postgres directory, then i go to manually add my own new directory and I get `mkdir: /usr/local/var/postgres: File exists` !? `psql` still says `no such file or directory`. Context on my situation:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088325/how-can-i-migrate-postgres-9-3-5-to-9-4-4-after-deleting-the-9-3-5-oldbindir

Comment: I had to follow this same process on my M1 Mac but with the brew path instead which for me was:
`/opt/homebrew/var/postgres`

Answer (score 14):

After trying to install postgresql with Homebrew, I got this:

```
Warning: postgresql-9.5.2 already installed, it's just not linked
```

So I tried:

```
brew link postgresql
```

And got this error:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.2... 
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man3/SPI_connect.3
/usr/local/share/man/man3 is not writable.
```

It seemed to be a write permission matter, so I did:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/share/man/
```

It did the trick because, then I was able to do (without error):

```
brew link postgresql
```

Answer (score 13):

In case anyone upgraded from a previous version, dont forget to:

```
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
```

That will solve the problem by upgrading your existing databases to the version you upgraded postgres to.

Comment: this fixed it for me.

Comment: Wow! Been googling this for hours! This fixed mine!

Answer (score 11):

Please note that their is a thread on Homebrew's github dealing with this issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/35240

---

I have had a similar issue. James answer helped me solve it. But I then ran into the issue jbk is mentioning (after having deleted /usr/local/var/postgres, it kept on being recreated).

The issue is that if you have created the symlink:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
```

and launched the process:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

you should first unload it:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

before running James's commands.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres  # in case this is not your first try
mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres
chmod 0700 /usr/local/var/postgres
```

In addition, if, like me, you have an admin user managing homebrew and a regular user who will be using pgsl for development purpose, James command should be run as super user:

```
sudo -s
```

and ownership over the postgres directory should be given to your dev user:

```
chown my-dev-user /usr/local/var/postgres
```

The following command, run as the dev user, should then properly populate the directory:

```
createdb `whoami`
```

Running:

```
psql -l
```

should show you the tables and user permissions in postgre after such manipulations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was amazing! Thank you Cedric. I had the same issue with permissions.

Answer (score 5):

I had to delete the `.pid` file after seeing this in the logs

`/usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`

```
2021-10-10 19:05:27.468 BST [41868] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
2021-10-10 19:05:27.468 BST [41868] HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 820) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
```

```sh
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

I installed it using brew

Comment: I have no idea why this problem happens in the first place, but this solved my problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

based on @James answer this is what I did on my M1 Monterey machine. For me the directory differed.

**DANGER: In the comments it has been pointed out that my script deletes the database.**

In terminal:

```
#to fix postgresql of existing installation
cd /opt/homebrew/var
rm -rf postgres
mkdir postgres
chmod 0700 postgres
initdb -D postgres

#install postgres
echo "installing postgres..."
brew install postgresql
brew services restart postgresql
createuser postgres -s
```

I then could `brew install --cask pgadmin4` and run pgadmin from Applications and connect to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: This works, unfortunately it also deletes the entire databases

Comment: added a danger db drop in text

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a problem which began when I upgraded some brew updates / upgrades, mainly python versions etc.  What worked for me.

```
brew uninstall postgres
brew install postgresql@9.5
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/postgresql@9.5/bin:$PATH"' > ~/.zshrc
# you may need > ~/.bashrc if you use bash
```

I needed pg_dump, pg_restore etc so to get that working I did

```
brew install libpq
```

Start the service

```
brew services start postgresql@9.5
```

From here I would have expected everything to work but still all rails db commands were giving error that server was not running.  This final bit was the missing piece of the puzzle which finally solved it for me.

```
gem uninstall pg
gem install pg -v 0.20.0 # which was set in Gemfile
# could also just probably do bundle install instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd this issue after shutting down the computer due power outage.

```
# This initialize your database with the current data and settings
initdb -D postgres

# This will start database service
pg_ctl -D postgres -l logfile start
```

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I had this issue and wanted to note what worked for me.

I am running postgres 11.2 on High Sierra. I had recently upgraded from postgres 10 with `brew postgresql-upgrade-database`.

I kept getting the error `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`, and my server.log indicated `is another postmaster (PID 5894) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?`

I tried several solutions including restarting my computer, deleting `postmaster.pid`, using `brew services restart postgres`, but to no avail. I eventually stumbled on the solution:

`brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql`

No idea why this worked, but putting it here mostly so I can reference it myself in the future! Throw stuff at the wall till it sticks!

Answer (score 0):

Check @leo_chaz_maltrait for fixing errors the error `Could not symlink share/man/man3/SPI_connect.3`
Another error that might show up is:

`Error: Could not symlink lib/pkgconfig/libecpg.pc`

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

brew link postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read and follow the instructions.

1. Check `postgres` logs to see what the issue is.

   - `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/postgres.log`
   - `tail -f /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgres.log`
   - `tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log`
2. In my case it this was the error.

   - `2022-07-19 21:16:12.095 IST [2138] FATAL:  data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" has invalid permissions`
   - `[3472] FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists`
3. Added the required permission and issue got fixed.

   - `sudo chown -R vikas /usr/local/var/postgres`
   - `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

That's it.