# psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am trying to install PostgreSQL on my MAC using `home brew` and when i try to run the command `psql` i am getting the following error

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Looks like the system is not recognizing the installation.

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ locate psql | grep /bin
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/bin/psql
/usr/local/bin/psql
```

The process seems to be running

```
    Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ ps -aef|grep postgres  
      501 12075 11832   0 11:54AM ttys001    0:00.00 grep postgres
```

Also the plist file

```
Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ launchctl load -w /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist  
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: Operation already in progress


Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ which psql
/usr/local/bin/psql

Harshas-MacBook-Pro:~ harshamv$ echo $PATH
/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/harshamv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/harshamv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Applications/bin/php5/bin/:/Applications/Mamp/htdocs/prayag/lib/Cake/Console:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/harshamv/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/mongodb/bin
```

Comment: The program asked you a question, what about `/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432`?  Do you have two versions of psql installed?

Comment: @Schwern how can i check that?

Comment: `ls -l /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` to check the temp file.  `which -a psql` to check for multiple installations.

Comment: @Schwern ls: /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: No such file or directory

Comment: @Schwern harshamv$ which -a psql
/usr/local/bin/psql

Answer (score 1):

You're not running a PostgreSQL server.  Your `ps` output only shows your own ps grep.

You also might have two versions of PostgreSQL installed and you're running the psql client associated with the wrong one.  You can run `which -a psql` to see all psql binaries in your PATH.

[The PostgreSQL Wiki has a page devoted to figuring out Homebrew problems](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Homebrew).

[This answer to your exact problem may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708774/14660).

Comment: in uninstalled and reinstalled it now i get harshamv$ which -a psql
/usr/local/bin/psql

Comment: @HarshaMV Good, you only have one installed.