# How can i migrate Postgres 9.3.5 to 9.4.4 after deleting the 9.3.5 oldbindir?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to migrate from Postgres 9.3.5 to 9.4.4 and in doing so I've removed the old 9.3.5 install of Postgres (running `brew cleanup` too early did this i think). Whilst following various sources info on how to upgrade I realise that in order to `pg_upgrade`I need the `oldbindir` to do so.

Is there any way around this and if so how. If not how can i reinstall the old version in the right way into the right location in order to then run pg_upgrade?

Some context to help you understand where I am:

```
brew info postgres

postgresql: stable 9.4.4 (bottled)
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with: postgres-xc
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.4 (3014 files, 40M) *
  Poured from bottle
From:     https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--32-bit
    Build 32-bit only
--with-dtrace
    Build with DTrace support
--with-python
    Build with python support
--without-perl
    Build without Perl support
--without-tcl
    Build without Tcl support
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/2510
```

greps return the following so server seems not to be running locally:

```
ps aux | grep postgres
501  1228   367   0 10:37am ttys000    0:00.01 grep postgres

ps aux | grep pgsql
501  1260   367   0 10:42am ttys000    0:00.01 grep pgsql
```

In `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql` I have only; `9.4.4`

In `/usr/local/var` I currently have:

`postgres.old` - where all of my old databases reside.
`postgres.old2`  - unsure of where this came from tbh, I had to `chown` it to get to look at contents, only `server.log` inside.
`postgres9.4.` - Full seemingly as it should be after having been initdb'd.
'postgres' - Empty, think this has been created in a failed pg_upgrade attempt.

Any help hugely appreciated, I've been on this for many hours now. Any more context info you require to help find the right solution out of this, just let me know. Thanks

Comment: Why is this a RVM or Ruby question?

Comment: Apologies @the Tin Man, you're absolutely right, tags edited accordingly.

Comment: this might help: https://gist.github.com/olivierlacan/e1bf5c34bc9f82e06bc0