# PG::ConnectionBad upgrade to Yosemite and postgresql 9.4.4

Tags: macos, postgresql, rails-4-2-1

I just updated my mac OS X to Yosemite, version 10.10.4, and postgresql to: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.4.

After running rake db:migrate on my Rails 4.2.1 application, my terminal session is responding with:

```
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Simply entering psql in my terminal session also appears a bit off:

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

After printing out the logs from, cat /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log, I read:

```
DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.4.
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.auto.conf"
FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite) on SO, but I a hesitant to just start creating a bunch of directories unless that's really what I am suppose to do. I also found an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgresql-error-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory) but am not too sure if it's the one to follow.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573204/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory-mac-os-x) suggests that I remove a, /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid, but I do not have one, I have a, /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.opts -- should I remove the postmaster.opts?

There appears to be lots of advice, but I am not too sure what to follow. Can someone offer some advice in getting my postgresql database running on my rails application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I had to drop and recreate my own database and re-seed it with remote staging data. What I did not understand is that the problem with updating a database is that the data itself also needs to be 'updated' in a way. The data was compatible with a different version

Answer (score 12):

You could upgrade the database by following an official guide:

```
brew switch postgres 9.3    # presuming you already installed 9.4.4
pg_dumpall > outputfile
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
mv /usr/local/var/postgres /usr/local/var/postgres.old
brew switch postgres 9.4.4
initdb -D /usr/local/var/postgres
psql -d postgres -f outputfile
```

[PostgreSQL upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/upgrading.html)

Comment: Definitely the cleaner move. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I had to start the DB after the `initdb`, with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`.

Comment: me, too. if using homebrew, restart postgresql with
`brew services restart postgresql`