# 1 [Ubuntu] Configuring Postgresql to talk to Rails App, stuck with no idea what to try next

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

Hi,

I'm setting up a new Acer-571 Chromebook running Ubuntu via Crouton, primarily for rails development.

I've installed postgresql and the pg gem in rails. I created a superuser brett when logged in as the user postgres, along with a database named brett.

I can verify that postgresql is running:

```
brett@localhost:~/Downloads/lcba/config$ service  postgresql status
Running clusters: 9.1/main 

brett@localhost:~/Downloads/lcba/config$ pg_lsclusters 
Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file
9.1     main      5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main       /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
```

I've configured my database.yml file to post to (what I believe is) the correct user and database that I created:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: brett
  host: localhost
  post: 5432
  password: brett_pass
  host: localhost

test:
  <<: *default
  database: brett_test
  host: localhost
  post: 5432
  database: brett
  password: brett_pass
```

I start my rails server, and head to localhost:3000, and receive the following error message in the logs about the pg connection:

```
  Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-04-24 15:11:35 -0700

PG::Error (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:436:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:446:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /home/brett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
  /home/brett/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:565:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:384:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:371:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0.beta3) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0)  lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run'
  puma (2.11.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Does anybody have any ideas or pointers in the right direction? I've been trying to get postgresql to work for the last two days to no avail. Ready and willing to provide any information or console output needed. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgresql-error-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Update: I continued to play around with multiple solutions until I noticed that my localhost was still throwing this error regardless of if a rails server was running. I found the process taking place on the port and killed it, and postgres was subsequently able to connect with a few minor modifications.

Check for ghost processes on your ports if you suffer from pg connect errors!

Answer (score 0):

In your config fix `post` to `port` for all the records:

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: brett
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Comment: In addition, maybe you should add **username: <yourpgusername>** as well