# Postgres Error after updating to Latest OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, postgresql

Hey guys i recently updated my mac to latest OS X 10.12.3
Previously my rails project was working fine, now whenever i start my rails server i keep getting this error for my project. I've tried a lot of different solution provided here in stackoverflow it simply still not working.

Here are some of it i've tried

[Postgres could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)

[PostgreSQL error 'Could not connect to server: No such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472988/postgresql-error-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory)

Thanks, please help me

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):

activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `new'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `connect'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:217:in `initialize'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:721:in `new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:765:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:744:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:705:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:501:in `checkout'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:875:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:558:in `connection'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:545:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in `call_app'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
/Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
/Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
/Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
  Rendering /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendering /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendering /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (98.5ms)
[2017-02-01 15:42:00] ERROR PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `initialize'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `new'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:671:in `connect'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:217:in `initialize'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `new'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:721:in `new_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:765:in `checkout_new_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:744:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:705:in `acquire_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:501:in `checkout'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:875:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:47:in `block in install_executor_hooks'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_complete_callbacks'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:107:in `complete!'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:13:in `block in call'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:23:in `close'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:115:in `service'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
    /Users/leo/.rbenv/versions/2.3.2/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Show your attempts to verify that the server is running. Show `netstat` output to check if the server is listening. Show `ls` output where you checked if the socket file exists. Show `listener_addresses` and `port` from `postgresql.conf`. Show suspicious PostgreSQL log entries. In short, help us to help you.

Comment: can u tell me the precise step. i'm very new in rails

here is netstat u mention.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzkrtj4d55ta3us/netstat.txt?dl=0

Comment: I'm afraid that's beyond the scope. Look for older questions about this error message (variants of it come up several times per day), and use `man` and web search to figure out how to use `netstat` and similar. All this has to be checked on the database server, so if you have no access to that, you need to ask the system administrators for help.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting your postgres server using this command:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Answer (score 0):

i found solution for this. Just download the postgres app

http://postgresapp.com/

Not sure if it will work for everyone, but it worked for me :)